# Redshift: how do I get a copy of my join table onto each slice in my cluster?

Tags: amazon-redshift

Imagine that I have a large fact table and a small and frequently changing join table.

The entire contents of my small join table probably fit on a slice.

How do I get copies of my join table pushed onto each slice (or at least each node) of my cluster?  If I could do that, wouldn't my joins be massively faster?

Answer (score 3):

Redshift recently added support for a new distribution type "DISTSTYLE ALL" that does exactly what the OP is looking for.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_choosing_dist_sort.html

Answer (score 0):

You may try to set a DISTRIBUTION KEY to the same column (both in a fact table and in a join table) - that way all rows that will be joined will land on the same nodes.

That will work ONLY if you have even distribution of values in a join column - only then data will be spread evenly across the nodes.

You can check data distribution for a table using a query:

```sql
select slice, col, num_values, minvalue, maxvalue
from svv_diskusage
where name = '__INSERT__TABLE__NAME__HERE__' and col = 0
order by slice, col;
```

You want to have similar values in a num_values column.